# Should I use the possessive apostrophe or an attribute noun on a business card?

Tags: writing-style, possessives, formality, apostrophe, attributive-nouns

I have designed some stationary items (such as letterhead and business card) for a website/brand (XYZ.Com for instance), and I need help to choose the correct sentence among those below:

> 1. The XYZ.Com'**s** Corporate Identity Set
> 2. The XYZ.Com Corporate Identity Set
> 3. The Corporate Identity Set **of** XYZ.Com

I guess neither of the sentences above is correct, the correct sentence would be something like "XYZ.Com Corporate Identity". Right?

The second question is, should I replace the noun "set" with "pack/package"?

Comment: Can anyone here help me structure the sentence?

Comment: I would definitely choose No.2. I cannot write a full answer now, but if no one does, I'll come back tomorrow. As to substituting "set" with "pack/age" I really don't know, they sound pretty much the same. But "set" is shorter and sounds sleeker. I'm not sure what an "identity set" is though that seems a little strange.

Comment: Should the no.2 begin with determiner "the"?

Answer (score 1):

This is partly a matter of style and opinion, but I would use, as a headline or title on a set of materials (for example), "Company Identity Guide." You don't need to emphasize possession. You would be completely correct to use this form:

XYZ.com Corporate Identity Guide

In contrast, consider that you might use the possessive form if you were describing a current project: "I'm working on XYZ.com's corporate identity guide."

Comment: OK, it's called [identity guide](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-create-a-clear-and-concise-brand-identity-guide--vector-5990) I didn't know that. Would calling it a *set* be misunderstood?

Comment: True I agree but does it sound incorrect if i use "pack/package" instead of "guide", Cause it's formally called corporate identity, also known as brand idenity, a set of elements/items such as business card, letterhead, logo, fonts and so forth.

Comment: Here's an example:

http://www.djavupixel.com/design/logo/corporate-identity-design-great-examples/

Comment: Corporate Identity Materials also works as a title for the actual package of logos, letterhead, business cards, etc.